# How to translate Linq/SQL to Lambda in c#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-core

How would one translate the Linq code below to Lambda type of query?

```
        var domainModel = (
                            from Hosps in _ctx.Hospital
                            from Room in _ctx.SickRoom
                                     .Where(x => x.HospitalId == Hosps.HospitalId)
                                     .GroupBy(x => x.HospitalId)
                                     .Select(x => new
                                     {
                                         HospitalId = x.Key,
                                         NumberOfFloors = x.Max(y => y.FloorId),
                                         NumberOfRooms = x.Count()
                                     })
                                     .OrderBy(x => x.HospitalId)
                            select new 
                            {
                                HospitalId = Hosps.HospitalId,
                                City = Hosps.City,
                                HospitalImage = Hosps.HospitalImage,
                                NumberOfFloors = Room.NumberOfFloors,
                                NumberOfApartments = Room.NumberOfRooms
                            }
                        ).ToList();
```

If it helps, the SQL query for the Linq expression above is:

```
SELECT [r].[HospitalId]
      ,[r].[City]
      ,[r].[HospitalImage]
      ,[t].[c] AS [NumberOfFloors]
      ,[t].[c0] AS [NumberOfRooms]
FROM [Hospital] AS [r] 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [a].[HospitalId], MAX([a].[FloorId]) AS [c], COUNT(*) AS [c0]
    FROM [SickRoom] AS [a]
    GROUP BY [a].[HospitalId]
) AS [t] ON [r].[HospitalId] = [t].[HospitalId]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a proper model taking relations into consideration, it would be like:

```
var domainModel = _ctx.Hospital.Select(h => 
                        new
                        {
                            HospitalId = h.HospitalId,
                            City = h.City,
                            HospitalImage = h.HospitalImage,
                            NumberOfFloors = h.SickRooms.Max(sr => sr.FloorId),
                            NumberOfApartments = h.SickRooms.Count()
                        })
                        .ToList();
```

Note that your SQL suggests that in your model there is a navigation to a hospital's SickRooms (h.SickRooms).

Comment: In that scenario it does not need to do a Include(SickRooms) to retrieve the data without throwing any null exception inside .Max?

Comment: @HeitorRibeiro, it would work fine. My suggestion is to download and install LinqPad (basic edition is free). You can see the generated SQL + test it fast.

Comment: @HeitorRibeiro, actually rethinking about it, you were right, if an hospital didn't have any SickRooms (seems unlikely) then this should cause a null exception. However, the fix would be simple by casting the result to int? instead of default int (NumberOfFloors = (int?)h.SickRooms...

Comment: To avoid that you can add the Include of the SickRooms or, you can put the h.SickRooms?.Max. As far as I know, it won't throw an exception doing like that. Because, if you are doing the Max withou veryfing that the SickRooms is null, even casting won't solve the problem

Comment: @HeitorRibeiro, casting would work. I just tried with Northwind customers (Hospitals) and Orders (SickRooms) using (int?)h.Orders.Max(o => o.OrderId) and Orders.Count() to be sure.